# Business Rules Engines in .NET with Designer

Tags: .net, business-rules

I'm looking for (preferably commercial) business rules engines in .NET that include a GUI designer that serializes the rules into something that can be stored in a database (preferably XML). I've looked at InRule and FlexRule, InRule hasn't gotten back to me about an evaluation and FlexRule doesn't seem to work on Windows 8. It'd be nice if the designer was in something like Silverlight so it can be hosted on the web.

What are the options for Business Rules Engines targeting .NET 4.0?

Comment: FlexRule works perfectly on Windows 8. Please contact their support to investigate your particular issues. They are very helpful and fast to resolving issues.

Comment: It does not. I have just installed it on Win 8.1 and unless I run it with admin privileges, it shows several errors related to access rights. Also, FlexRule looks a bit dated, not quite what I expect for the 12k USD price tag.

Comment: It seems you are talking about FlexRule Designer which requires that permission. Please ensure you have full access in the folder you install it. Alternatively you can install it in other partition than your OS.